# Git rebase trunk onto topic

Tags: git

Looking at my Git tree I have this (Note: Feature2 branches off from Feature1)

```
----b---c---d -"Feature1"
  \
   \--e---f---g -"Feature2"
```

I want to rebase Feature1 (b, c, d) onto Feature2 so it would read e-f-g-b-c-d. When I run the rebase the 3 way merge kicks in seems to favor Feature2 and b, c and d's changes seem to disappear.

**How can I rebase where the merging favors Feature1?**

The typical rebase scenario I run into has a tree that looks like this (Note Feature1 branches off Feature2):

```
--e---f---g -"Feature2"
\
 \--b---c---d -"Feature1"
```

Then it would rebase cleanly as Feature1 is historically based off Feature2. However I notice my current situation Feature2 branches off Feature1.

Comment: Do you have conflicts? If yes, you just perform the resolution. If not, I'm not sure what you mean by "favoring". Could you provide an example?

Comment: Yes there were conflicts which seemed to kick off the 3 way merge strategy. By favoring I mean the merge has a choice of using the file contents from Feature1 vs Feature2 to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Does `git rebase -s recursive -X theirs Feature2 Feature1` help?

Comment: Yes it appears git rebase -s recursive -X ours Feature2 seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git rebase uses merges to merge one commit after another onto the branch you want to rebase on. This means you can use all [available merge strategies](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies) for rebases as well. The default merge strategy is `recursive` which is for three way merges. It can be further customized; in your case the branch to be rebased should be favored. This corresponds to the `theirs` option (remember, sides are switched in a rebase):

```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs Feature2 Feature1
```